# Cannot create VM thread. Out of system resources when running spigot buildtools

Tags: java, server, minecraft

I'm trying to setup a minecraft spigot server on a gamemanagement pannnel called pufferpanel.
The panel creates a second user called pufferpanel which runs all commands.
Now when I install the server with this command:

```
java -jar BuildTools.jar --rev lastest
```

But this throws me out this error:

```
Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 4k, detached.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Cannot create VM thread. Out of system resources.
```

The current serverload is `500M(b) from 8G(b)`.
When I do the same with the root account it worked.

I checked ulimit(`ulimit -a`) for the current user(pufferpanel) and for root:

- Root(user):

  core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
  data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
  scheduling priority             (-e) 0
  file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
  pending signals                 (-i) 4125393
  max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
  max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
  open files                      (-n) 1024
  pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
  POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
  real-time priority              (-r) 0
  stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
  cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
  max user processes              (-u) 7000000
  virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
  file locks                      (-x) unlimited
- Pufferpanel(user):

  time(seconds)        unlimited
  file(blocks)         unlimited
  data(kbytes)         unlimited
  stack(kbytes)        8192
  coredump(blocks)     0
  memory(kbytes)       unlimited
  locked memory(kbytes) 65536
  process              7000000
  nofiles              1024
  vmemory(kbytes)      unlimited
  locks                unlimited
  rtprio               0

I really doesn't know what could be the problem. I still want to use the pannel as it allows me to manage user acces to the server and has automatic restart.

Comment: can you check both of the users see the same `java`? also, perhaps reducing the stack size (by `-Xss512k`) may help.

Comment: How can I check if both users see the same java? If it is `which java` then its the same.
And which command run with your mentioned flag `-Xss512k`?

Comment: I meant `java -Xss512k -jar BuildTools.jar --rev lastest`. This will reduce the stack size and perhaps may avoid that exception, but will unfortunately not explain (at least to me) the behavior difference between users.

Comment: This gives me this error:
https://pastebin.com/Jm7Bga7L

Comment: it looks like the same error, but it reported that it couldn't start the gc thread. can you try to run `java -version`? does that even work? it must be caused by some limitation of the user, but open files, stack size, memory limits seems identical with root, so really out of ideas. you can also try comparing `env` for both users, maybe you can spot something..

Comment: java -version gives me:
java version
"17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Just, it's not `lastest` but `latest`